# how to make a variable readonly with in a if statement only when is true in php

Tags: php

How can I make the $srf_9 read only if is true and also $srf_9_explain when is true. Below is what I have I know it must be a simple code but I'm new to php and still learning the basics. Can this be done with throwing a new exception or is it done with the $variable that is calling for? Anyhelp or comments will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
 if($id <= 71){ $srf_7n = $row[srf_9]; }
 else $srf_7n = ($_GET['convert'] == 'true') ? $row2[srf_7n] : $row[srf_7n];
 echo fill('<select name="srf_7n" id="srf_7n" size="1">
   <option value="ChooseFromDropDownMenu">Choose From Drop Down Menu</option>
   <option value="Yes - Explain.">Yes - Explain</option>
   <option value="No - Explain.">No - Explain</option>
   <option value=" - "> - </option>
   </select>', $srf_7n);
if($id <= 71){ $srf_7n_explain = $row[srf_9_explain] : throw new Exception("$srf_9_explain = readonly"); }
else $srf_7n_explain = ($_GET['convert'] == 'true') ? $row2[srf_7n_explain] : $row[srf_7n_explain];
echo fill('<input id="srf_7n_explain" name="srf_7n_explain" type="text" style="width:650px;" value="" />', $srf_7n_explain);
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "make $srf_9 read only"? $srf_9 is a varaible.

Comment: What ever $variable is equal to I want it to be readonly when the if statement is true. example if $srf_9 is "hello" I want it readonly.

Comment: You want a PHP variable to be readonly?

Comment: Agree with @Popnoodles here.  You do not get bonus points for cramming code into as few lines as possible.  You question is unclear here.

Comment: @user3324559 Why not define a constant?  It sounds like this might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I dont even know what the points are for.   ANYWAYS is it possible to make $variable to be set as readonly after the statement is true?? Do guys understand???